# Windows Phone 7 Emulator Internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, window

I am really struggling to get the Windows Phone 7 emulator connecting to the internet. The following things are not an issue:

- My proxy settings are correct. I can browse the internet through IE and my colleague can connect with the same settings.
- I do not have fiddler installed so this should not be causing problems.
- I receive no error messages starting up the emulator or using the emulator.

I have uninstalled and re installed the SDK and patched it to the latest version but all of this to avail.

I get the same problem when my phone is connected to my computer, it will stop me being able to browse the internet through my phone.

It is probably worth noting that I can get to internal sites, which are either defined in my exception list, or forwarded on to internal DNS from the proxy server.

Running on Windows 7 Pro x64.

Comment: Just to be sure you are not able to visit a website via IE in the emulator but, you can with the browser on your computer. Also you are not running the SDK on a virtual machine. Is that so?

Comment: `Some proxy configuration options are not supported on Windows Phone` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff754351(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Interesting, but to answer both of you, I can browse internet using IE or chrome on my PC but I am not able to do so on a phone connected to my machine or on an emulator. I am not too bothered about my proxy exception list as I have recently changed the proxy server to perform this instead. Also, I am at work and my proxy does not require authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about testing with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if connections are emanating from the emulator when you use the browser to visit a site. The reasons for failing to use the Internet can be at many levels. Let's first eliminate the fact that the emulator is sending HTTP requests out. Do you know how to use Wireshark?

Comment: Cannot see any requests from the emulator.

Comment: Also, if I browse internal websites, it seems to be resolving host name without using the proxy.

Comment: So, you are able to browse (i.e. you can see HTTP requests from the emulator via Wireshark) internal websites via the IE on the emulator?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I can see traffic going everywhere but the proxy.

Comment: I think we can move forward and look at the configurations on the pc because clearly the problem is not in the emulator. I wonder if altering the %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file would help debug the situation further. E.g. would you be able to define some domain name to first point to an Internal IP and then test. Afterwards we can repeat the experiment so that the domain name points to an external IP. Also, i think that we might have to look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff754351%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: @boburob Any new info or progress on the issue? It would be nice to know how to solved it or if you would have further updates.

Comment: Gros, just managed to get it working using just IP addreses. Seems to be some sort of DNS resolution issue, not really sure why I didnt test this in the first place, using IP's is fine for me so I am happy for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use something like a Proxifier - a tool that *can* redirect outcoming requests to the proxy, because WP7 emulator doesn't support proxy as I know.